# object type scrollTo?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to load a object as text/html, then once it loads have it jump to 200,200 using scrollTo(). Regardless of what I try I can not get it to happen.

```
<html>
<object 
    type="text/html"
    id="stats" 
    width="1000" 
    height="300" 
    data="http://slashdot.org"
    onload="document.getElementById('stats').document.body.innerHTML.scrollTo(200,200)">
</object>
</html>
```

Is there something I am missing with how I am supposed to grab the object?

I am using slashdot.org as an example, the page will be on the same domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your loaded data will be on the same domain — you can use:

```
onload="this.contentDocument.defaultView.scrollTo(200, 200)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in your javascript error console. You can't scroll to on an `innerHTML`. Remove the `innerHTML` and see if it works.